# how to read the formatted file in C++

Tags: c++

I have the following format. Each line has two integers and the file is ended by "*". How can I read the two numbers from the file. Thanks.

```
4 5
7 8
78 89
 *  //end of file
```

**Edit**

I know read the two numbers but do not know how to deal with "*". If I store each number as integer type and read them by `cin`. But The last line is a string type. So the problem is that I read it as a integer but it is string, I do not how to judge whether it is * or not.

My code was as follows (it is obviously incorrect):

```
string strLine,strChar;
istringstream istr;
int a,b;
while(getline(fin,strChar))
{
    istr.str(strLine);
    istr>> ws; 
    istr>>strChar;


    if (strChar=="*")
    {
        break;
    }
    istr>>a>>b;
}
```

Comment: The below link would help you in solving this.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply pull the numbers from the `ifstream` object until it fails.

```
std::ifstream fin("file.txt");

int num1, num2;
while (fin >> num1 >> num2)
{
    // do whatever with num1 and num2
}
```

Comment: +1 for the obvious, simple solution, which happens to satisfy all of the OP's stated constraints. K.I.S.S.

Answer (score 1):

I preffer to use good old [fscanf() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb5kac8b%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), see a simple and straightforward example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb5kac8b%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

1. As first step read entire line into a string buffer
2. Check whether it equals to "*"
3. If not - use [sscanf()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkx076cy%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to parse two integers

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use `std::istream` to read the file line by line.  Then, process each input line and store the numbers into a list.

```
// open the file.
std::string path = "path/to/you/file";
std::ifstream file(path.c_str());
if (!file.is_open()) {
    // somehow process error.
}

// read file line by line.
std::vector< std::pair<int,int> > numbers;
for (std::string line; std::getline(file,line);)
{
    // prepare to parse line contents.
    std::istringstream parser(line);

    // stop parsing when first non-space character is '*'.
    if ((parser >> std::ws) && (parser.peek() == '*')) {
       break;
    }

    // store numbers in list of pairs.
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    if ((parser >> i) && (parser >> j)) {
        numbers.push_back(std::make_pair(i, j));
    }
}
```

Comment: My original thinking is the almost same as you, But my problem is that I do not know `peek()`. Thanks